# How do I write a function that looks like it takes a list of function names and variable arguments for each function_name

Tags: python, function, arguments

Finding it a little difficult to find a good title, apologies if this one is misleading..

I would like to write a function that will take other functions (an their possible arguments) along with other arguments.

for example, I have the following functions:

```
def f1():
    pass

def f2(arg1):
    pass

def f3(arg1, arg2):
    pass
```

so my function would like to look like this

```
def master(mandatory_arg, f1, f2, arg1, f3, arg1, arg2, ...):
    mandatory_arg = some_value
    f1()
    f2(arg1)
    f3(arg1, arg2)
```

Actually, the function signature would probably have to look like this:

```
def master(mandatory_arg, *args):
    #magic happens here to parse * args
    #call each function with its argument list
```

I do not know how many functions (and args will be passed to the function. What would be the best way to write this function?

This function (master) will be used by fairly non-technical people, so I want to make it as easy for them as possible.

My question is, how do I parse *args to get the function names and arguments for each function passed into *args.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish - what problem is this supposed to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use callable, or inspect, inspect will tell you how many parameter the function need:

```
import inspect
def master(mandatory_arg, *args):
    args = list(args)
    while args:
        f = args.pop(0)
        n = len(inspect.getargspec(f).args)
        p, args = args[:n], args[n:]
        f(*p)

master(mandatory_arg, f1, f2, 'a1', f3, 'a1', 'a2')
```

Comment: Question: What if one of my functions takes a default argument?

    def f2(arg1=None):
        pass

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use as arguments a list of functions (lfunc) and a list of arguments (larg) to be passed to the functions

```
def master(mandatory_arg, lfunc, larg):
    for k,fun in enumerate(lfunc):
        fun(larg[:k])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`callable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable) function to determine which elements of `args` are functions and which are arguments, e.g.:

```
def master(mandatory_arg, *args):
    # Do something with mandatory_arg here
    func = None
    funcArgs = []
    for a in args:
        if callable(a):
            if func is not None: func(*funcArgs)
            func = a
            funcArgs = []
        else:
            funcArgs.append(a)
    if func is not None: func(*funcArgs)
```